# Can there be self loops for undirected graphs?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I mean directed graphs can have a self-loop, so I don't see the reason why an undirected graph cannot have it (CLRS says it's forbidden without giving a valid reason).

```
Example: 

G_directed = (V,E) is a directed graph

Say this graph has the vertex set V = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

With edges E = {(1,2),(2,2),(2,4),(2,5),(4,1),(4,5),(5,4),(6,3)}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Say we now decide to turn G_directed into an undirected graph:

G_undirected = (Vu,Eu) is an undirected graph

Vu = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

With edges E = {(1,2),(2,2),(2,4),(2,5),(4,1),(4,5),(6,3)}
```

In the example (2,2) is the **self loop**. I seriously don't see any problems this can have with graph traversals.

Comment: Do you have a question?  By definition, every edge in an undirected graph generates a cycle.  So, the discussion of cycles in undirected graphs is, shall I say, not as well developed as the discussion of cycles in directed graphs.

Answer (score 4):

There are several categories of undirected graphs. Where loops (self references) are not allowed, they are called [simple graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Simple_graph). But there is indeed no reason to consider undirected graphs with loops and even multiple edges between the same pair of nodes: these are called [multigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Multigraph):

> A loop is an edge (directed or undirected) that connects a vertex to itself; it may be permitted or not, according to the application.
>
> A multigraph, as opposed to a simple graph, is an undirected graph in which multiple edges (and sometimes loops) are allowed.